# Export data from Excel into XML with variable elements

Tags: xml, excel, xsd

I need to create XML documents but want to automate the process using Excel because I can't copy and paste hundreds of values into the XML document.  I am new to this feature of Excel though and am having trouble with the layout of the elements.  This is an example of the final XML document:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<ANALYSIS_SET>
    <ANALYSIS alias="Test Analysis 1" center_name="NeurOmics" broker_name="EGA" xmlns:com="SRA.common" xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance">
        <TITLE>Bed data hsp 1</TITLE>
        <DESCRIPTION>Test of NeurOmics Tuebingen HSP Data 1</DESCRIPTION>
        <STUDY_REF accession="EGAS00001000697"></STUDY_REF>
        <SAMPLE_REF accession="EGAN00001409012"></SAMPLE_REF>
        <RUN_REF accession="EGAR00001446342"></RUN_REF>
        <SAMPLE_REF accession="EGAN00001409040"></SAMPLE_REF>
        <RUN_REF accession="EGAR00001446343"></RUN_REF>
        <SAMPLE_REF accession="EGAN00001404184"></SAMPLE_REF>
        <RUN_REF accession="EGAR000016818343"></RUN_REF>
        <SAMPLE_REF accession="EGAN0000148740"></SAMPLE_REF>
        <RUN_REF accession="EGAR00001431643"></RUN_REF>
        <ANALYSIS_TYPE>
            <SEQUENCE_ANNOTATION/>
        </ANALYSIS_TYPE>
        <FILES>
            <FILE filename="TUE-hpHSPv2_TargetRegions.bed" filetype="bed"/>
        </FILES>
    </ANALYSIS>
    <ANALYSIS alias="Test Analysis 2" center_name="NeurOmics" broker_name="EGA" xmlns:com="SRA.common" xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance">
        <TITLE>BED data ataxia 1</TITLE>
        <DESCRIPTION>Test of NeurOmics Tuebingen Ataxia Data 1</DESCRIPTION>
        <STUDY_REF accession="EGAS00001000694"></STUDY_REF>
        <SAMPLE_REF accession="EGAN00001408934"></SAMPLE_REF>
        <RUN_REF accession="EGAR00001446272"></RUN_REF>
        <SAMPLE_REF accession="EGAN00001408935"></SAMPLE_REF>
        <RUN_REF accession="EGAR00001446271"></RUN_REF>
        <ANALYSIS_TYPE>
            <SEQUENCE_ANNOTATION/>
        </ANALYSIS_TYPE>
        <FILES>
            <FILE filename="TUE-hpSCAv1_TargetRegions.bed" filetype="bed"/>
        </FILES>
    </ANALYSIS>
```

The part I'm having trouble with are the elements `SAMPLE_REF` and `RUN_REF` as within each `ANALYSIS` section there can be any number of these paired values.  The rest I think I can figure out, for now I'm just trying to get that part in a format I can copy into the XML document as that's the part that will take all the time.  Anyway, I set up this `XSD` file for Excel:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8" standalone="no" ?>
<xsd:schema xmlns:xsd="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema">
    <xsd:element name="ANALYSIS_SET">
        <xsd:complexType>
            <xsd:sequence>
                <xsd:element name="ANALYSIS" minOccurs="0" maxOccurs="unbounded">
                    <xsd:complexType>
                        <xsd:sequence>
                            <!-- single sample information -->
                            <xsd:element name="refname" type="xsd:string"/>
                            <xsd:element name="accession" type="xsd:string"/>
                        </xsd:sequence>
                    </xsd:complexType>
                </xsd:element>
            </xsd:sequence>
        </xsd:complexType>
    </xsd:element>
</xsd:schema>
```

I then link this to an Excel spreadsheet which has a column for `refname` and a column for `accession`, and then export to XML.  This is what I get:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8" standalone="yes"?>
<ANALYSIS_SET>
    <ANALYSIS>
        <refname>GS130178</refname>
        <accession>EGAR00001446342</accession>
    </ANALYSIS>
    <ANALYSIS>
        <refname>GS130627</refname>
        <accession>EGAR00001446343</accession>
    </ANALYSIS>
    <ANALYSIS>
        <refname>GS130781</refname>
        <accession>EGAR00001446344</accession>
    </ANALYSIS>
    <ANALYSIS>
        <refname>GS130782</refname>
        <accession>EGAR00001446345</accession>
    </ANALYSIS>
    <ANALYSIS>
        <refname>GS130783</refname>
        <accession>EGAR00001446346</accession>
    </ANALYSIS>
    <ANALYSIS>
        <refname>GS130843</refname>
        <accession>EGAR00001446348</accession>
    </ANALYSIS>
<ANALYSIS_SET>
```

The problem I have is that I don't want each pair to be nested within an `ANALYSIS` tag, I want all the `refname`-`accession` pairs to be within a single `ANALYSIS` section.

Comment: The element definitions for  `refname` and `accession` would have the attributes `minOccurs="0" maxOccurs="unbounded"` to get. But then you are running into the Excel restriction that the Excel XML export cannot export lists of lists, https://support.office.com/en-ie/article/Issue-Verifying-an-XML-map-for-export-fbfcdb77-c2d6-4040-b256-e584a71151b0. Is using VBA an option?

Comment: Oh, that sucks then. I don't know VBA so can't really use that. Maybe JavaScript?