# Excel (2016) data export to xml

Tags: excel

Hello guys i have a question . I export from excel some data values but i want use a format like this.

```
<item id="1" name="Pablo" lastname="Escobar" type="Drugs">
        <set imageName="Pablo Escobar" link="escobar.com" />
</item>
```

I want use it from excel 
Thank you .

Comment: Unfortunately the information you provided is not sufficient enough for us to help you. How about adding more clarity?

Comment: I want add info on <item info1="" info2="">

I dont know how i do it with maps.

Comment: So whats this?..

Comment: Like this i wamt add element on <item element1="1">

https://stackoverflow.com/questions/37880341/export-data-from-excel-into-xml-with-variable-elements?rq=1